# Python - concatenate NoneType and string in a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Problem

How to concatenate None and string inside a new list?

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = 'apple,banana,cherry'
>>> new_list = a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
>>>
```

## Expected output

```
>>> new_list = [None, 'apple,banana,cherry']
>>> print(new_list)
[None, 'apple,banana,cherry']
>>> print(type(new_list))
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Comment: `new_list = [a, b]`

Comment: If you use list concatenation, both `a` and `b` must be lists: `a = [None]`, `b=['apple,banana,cherry']`.

Comment: Both the codes are different and hence the different result. Use the expected output code to get the expected result. Can you please explain a bit about your doubt?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez Thanks so much! It works now!

Answer (score 1):

to add items to a list you want to use the append method:

```
my_list = []
a = None
b = 'apple,banana,cherry'

# adds a to the list
my_list.append(a)

# adds b to the list
my_list.append(b)
```